# No longer able to checkout opencv_candidate in revision 50974, how is this possible?

Tags: ros, svn, rosinstall, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where to find SVN repository for package **opencv_candidate**? I did a SVN checkout a couple of weeks ago, but the SVN URL is no longer valid.

I am using package opencv_candidate in SVN revision 50974. It seems that the URL to https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/branches/trunk_diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate is no longer valid, and now just returns "HTTP 404 Not Found". It worked for the last months. If you look at https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/branches/trunk_diamondback/stacks, there's not even vision_bleeding to be found.

Now, the following behaviour is puzzling me.

> svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/branches/trunk_diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate

fails with

> svn: URL
> 'https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/branches/trunk_diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate'
> doesn't exist

which might be OK, since this sub-directory in the wg-ros-pkg might have been deleted in a commit after 50974, yet

> svn co -r 50974 https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/branches/trunk_diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate

fails with

> svn: '/svn/wg-ros-pkg/!svn/bc/51716/branches/trunk_diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate' path not found

whilst on my SVN working copy (that I've checked out way earlier) the following works

> svn info

properly printing

> Path: .

> URL: https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/branches/trunk_diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate

> Repository Root: https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg

> Repository UUID: 7275ad9f-c29b-430a-bdc5-66f4b3af1622

> Revision: 50974

> [...]

and also

> svn update -r 51400

actually retrieves files and prints as expected

> At revision 51400.

Puzzling though that

> svn update

leads to

> svn: Target path does not exist

Finally, I just want to retrieve opencv_candidate in revision 50479 (it should not disappear from history, right?), but rosinstall will fail to retrieving opencv_candidate in that revision. What am I doing wrong here? Anybody else using opencv_candidate, and having similar issues?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10161/no-longer-able-to-checkout-opencv_candidate-in-revision-50974,-how-is-this-possible?/) by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 960 on 2011-06-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The directory was renamed, see this answer http://answers.ros.org/question/1042/vision_bleeding-not-found.

If you want to checkout the old version you have to use different syntax.  (It's an odd bug in the svn client.)

```
svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/branches/trunk_diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate@50974
```

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on 2011-06-04**:
Thanks, that solved the issue! Your response made me do further research (this time on SVN). It's not a bug! See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html . So, I will have to take the blame, and the SVN client actual works correctly here!